# Как в SOAP response вывести свой результат

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

У меня есть web-сервис (JAX-WS), который выводит

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="body" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <ns3:requestDataResponse xmlns:ns2="http://uslugi.ru/rev" xmlns:ns3="http://services" xmlns:ns4="http://services">
         <ResponseData>
            <message>
               <status>Normul</status>
            </message>
            <messageData>
               <appData>
                  <response>
                     <fio>
                        <firstName>ima</firstName>
                     </fio>
                  </response>
               </appData>
            </messageData>
         </ResponseData>
      </ns3:requestDataResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

и мне хотелось бы, чтобы он выводил без requestDataResponse, т.е. в Body был только ResponseData.

ResponseData

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ResponseData", namespace = "http://uslugi.ru/rev")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ResponseData
{
    @XmlElement
    private Message message;
    @XmlElement
    private MessageData messageData;

    public Message getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public MessageData getMessageData()
    {
        return messageData;
    }

    public void setMessageData(MessageData messageData)
    {
        this.messageData = messageData;
    }
}
```

сервис и метод

```
@WebService(name = "IRequest", targetNamespace = "http://services")
public interface IRequest
{
@WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "ResponseData")
    public ResponseData requestData(
            @WebParam(name = "Header", header = true) Header header, 
            @WebParam(name = "Message") Message message, 
            @WebParam(name = "MessageData") MessageData messageData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Единственный способ, который нашёл, так это в хендлере чистить body,а потом заполнять своими данными. Побороть стандартные пространства имён не получилось, кто-то писал про packege-info и @XmlSchema, но я такой способ не пробывал

Answer (score 0):

У библиотек для веб-сервисов обычно присутствует инструмент для генерации скелета сервиса по WSDL-описанию. Составьте для своего сервиса нужный WSDL и воспользуйтесь этим инструментом.

Если не получится - меняйте используемую библиотеку.

Comment: Я описываю весь скелет через классы, говорю, что будет на входе и что на выходе, только на выходе всё описанное попадает в элемент имя которого соответствует названию метода + "Response" (к примеру, requestDataResponse). Так же все пространства имён сбивают в кашу, даже если их проставить, то тогда префиксы имеют стандартные имена (ns1, ns2, ...), которые в хендлере придётся удалять и снова прописывать, чтобы они назывались, как мне надо.

Comment: Вы решаете странную задачу странным методом. Если вам надо быстро сделать веб-сервис - то не пофиг ли, как оно там в XML будет? А если вам надо получить XML с определенной схемой - то надо составить WSDL и из него уже сгенерировать сервис.

Comment: Кажется, я понял вашу мысль. Обязательно попробую, спасибо